# How to modify heartbeat interval in SailsJs application?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

SailsJs integrates socket.io. How can I set heartbeat interval for its socket.io connection in a SailsJs application? Could not find documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `pingInterval` and `pingTimeout` in `config/sockets.js`

See here:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-sockets

Answer (score -1):

The client usually specifies the heartbeat.  Something like this:

```
var socket = io.connect(url);
socket.heartbeatTimeout = 20000;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Sails. _socket.socket.io doesn't expose those properties.

Comment: @cis Keep in mind this was about 2.5 years ago.  I'm sure the library has changed significantly since then.  I don't work with it anymore so I really can't comment on how to do this in 2018